# htmx - keep one specific div within a target unchanged

Tags: htmx

In the middle of a screen users can filter, scroll, etc. and submit forms. When they do, most details on the screen changes. I've achieved that by using an htmx-event as a trigger and it works nicely:

```
  <div
    id="large-section"
    hx-get="/large-section-details/"
    hx-trigger="sectionUpdated from:body"
  >
    <div>Some section content which gets updated</div>
    <div>Some more section content which gets updated</div>
    <div>
     I would like this div only to remain unchanged when `sectionUpdated` is raised. 
    </div>
    <div>Some more section content which gets updated</div>
    <div>Some more section content which gets updated</div>
  </div>
```

The only issue I have is that the filtering, scrolling etc. in that particular section is lost as it is part of the reloaded `div` too. I would like to exclude it. In other words, I'd like everything except one specific `div` to be reloaded. Is there an easy way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [hx-preserve](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-preserve/) attribute on that element. Make sure you also add a unique id attribute to the div.

```
<div id="large-section" hx-get="/large-section-details/" hx-trigger="sectionUpdated from:body">
  <div>Some section content which gets updated</div>
  <div>Some more section content which gets updated</div>
  <div id="unique-id" hx-preserve>
    I would like this div only to remain unchanged when `sectionUpdated` is raised.
  </div>
  <div>Some more section content which gets updated</div>
  <div>Some more section content which gets updated</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Quick note, that doesn't preserve the scrolling but that's good enough in my case.

Comment: It also doesn't work for iframes, and some other types of elements. For those you can try using the morphdom or idiomorph extensions.